# Azure DevOps Yaml - Update dynamic # of DBs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, flyway

Currently, I am using DevOps Pipelines YAML to run a **flyway** cli to perform migrations to a single Database. When code gets pushed, yaml triggers and runs flyway which updates DB.

We are planning to create multiple instances of this DB. However, the DB instances are created dynamically. We plan to store connection strings in a master DB + Key Vault.

Is it possible to achieve the following?

1. Code gets commit
2. YAML queries master DB, and gets X number connection strings
3. YAML loops X, and runs flyway for each connection string
4. All DBs gets updated

I do not think there is such a way. An alternative I can think of is create a Console Application that does the querying + calling flyway, and YAML just calls this in the build server.

Comment: you can do it with PowerShell script inside the YAML.

Comment: Ahh yes, PowerShell can work too. That is good idea. Thanks

Comment: If you facing issued with the script you can edit the question with the issue..